# Better way to encrypt & decrypt audio inBlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, encryption

I use this code to play decrypted audio on BlackBerry on the fly (for the sake of simplicity, I use [TEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm))

```java
public void play(String path){
    try {
        FileConnection fc = (FileConnection) Connector.open(path,   Connector.READ);
        InputStream is = fc.openInputStream();
        byte[] rawData = IOUtilities.streamToBytes(is);
        processEncryptedAudio(rawData);
        is.close();
        fc.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex){

    }
}

// TEA code is taken from http://www.winterwell.com/software/TEA.php
private void processEncryptedAudio(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    TEA tea = new TEA("ABCDE ABCDE ABC A ABCDEF".getBytes());
    byte[] decrypted_data = tea.decrypt(data);
    ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decrypted_data);
    ByteArrayInputStreamDataSource source = new ByteArrayInputStreamDataSource(stream, "audio/mpeg");

    try {
        player = Manager.createPlayer(source);
        player.start();
    }
    catch (MediaException me){
        Dialog.alert("MediaException: "+me.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem is decryption takes quite long time to finish. For example: on simulator, decrypting a 9 MB audio takes around 5 secs, but on BlackBerry Torch 9860 it takes more than 20 secs.

**Is there any way to improve this?** Actually the whole file doesn't neet to be encrypted, as long as it is obscured/cannot be played directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try switching from TEA to [RC4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), which is also very simple to implement and quite possibly faster.

Also, it looks like you're doing some unnecessary data copying: it would be slightly more efficient to make your `decrypt()` method modify the input byte array directly.  This may require changing the calling code to skip some number of bytes at the beginning and/or end of the decrypted data, but that shouldn't be too hard.  (The `ByteArrayInputStream` constructor can take optional `offset` and `length` arguments.)

If you want to get really fancy, you could try writing your own custom `InputStream` subclass that does the decryption "on the fly" while the audio is playing.  If you use a block cipher in [CTR, CFB or CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) (or ECB, but that's not secure), you can even make the stream seekable.  If you want to be even fancier, make it a wrapper around the original `InputStream` so that you can do the loading, decryption and playing *all* at the same time.

Another option might be to use the [RIM Crypto API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21091/RIM_Cryptographic_API_1304152_11.jsp), whose cipher implementations might be more efficient (possibly implemented in optimized native code) than your own.  The Crypto API also already provides the [`DecryptorInputStream` class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/DecryptorInputStream.html) which works in the manner I described above.

One possible down side is that the Crypto API seems to be only available to signed apps.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at RIM Crypto API. Hopefully I don't have to do much modifications. By the way, writing your own custom InputStream also looks interesting. I've never done that before. Maybe you have some snippet to share?

Comment: @anta40: Not really, but basically you'd just look at the [InputStream](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/java/io/InputStream.html) (or [SourceStream](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/protocol/SourceStream.html)) docs and think about how to implement all those methods. (Some of them can be left unimplemented if you want, and if you're wrapping another stream, you can delegate many of the methods more or less directly to the wrapped stream.)

Comment: OK, before that, I tried another method, which is reading the file chunks by chunks: http://pastebin.com/wsgK17pA. Tried that on device, and I couldn't hear anything. Wonder why :/

Comment: The player probably needs access to the whole audio stream, it can't make sense of just a piece of it, at least not if the piece is from the middle of the stream.  Also, you'll probably need to remember (at least) the IV if you want to do the decryption in multiple chunks.

Comment: [Initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Initialization_vector_.28IV.29). I assumed you were using a cipher mode that had one; if not, you really should be.